# Automated test between Win-app and Web-app

Tags: windows, user-interface, selenium, automated-tests, autoit

I have two applications where the Windows-desktop-application is for administration of the datainput and the web-application is for visualisation and report generation.

Is there a way to automate tests where the test can do one thing in the Win-app, continue in the wep-app and go back again to the Win-app in one testcase?

I have been trying to combine AutoIt for Win-app and Selenium for the web-app, but have problem to orchestrate both from one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to automate both Windows and web application. I would suggest to go with [Sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html) for Windows (non-web-) Applications. Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components.

And most people are combining Selenium and Sikuli for their automation and many [examples](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/sikuli-tutorial-part-2/) are [available](http://devengineering.com/blog/testing/how-integrate-sikuli-script-selenium-webdriver) in the internet. And it is easy to use. All you have to do is store the element as images and perform operations on them. You can also use AutoIt along with it.